# Need to extract the listings metadata SEQUENTIALLY but all the tags are identical - how to retrieve?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-crawler

I am trying to retrieve the postings metadata (green buttons & brown buttons) as shown below in the image in red.

[image: Green Button and Brown Button]

In the HTML tags they are under the same class and tags for each list so I end up either printing all of ONLY green button metadata or ONLY brown button metadata instead of Printing them both sequentially in order with the posts, as shown below in the second image

[image: Green Button and Brown Button html structure]

I literally spent 2 days and came up with no answer. Could anyone lend a hand?

For those who are interested in seeing the original website

website url:https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords=&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1=66&search_cat2=0

Ideally if there was a way to extract data from
a single Listing - Extract GreenButton Metadata & BrownButton Metadata
Move to second listing and do the same until there is no more listing

Been at it for so long that my brain is now in the edge of melting...

current code is as below (prints Only GreenButton Metadata and BrownButton Metadata= Wrong T_T)

```
postContainer = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id="post_list2"]')
            for li in postContainer:
                print('Thumbnail', li.find_element_by_css_selector(
                    'img').get_attribute('src'))
                # totalMetadataCount = li.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                #     'span.cat-category')[1].get_attribute('title')
                postMetadataContainer = []
                for category in li.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.cat-category'):
                    print(category.get_attribute('title'))
                for category in li.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.cat-category2'):
                    print(category.get_attribute('title'))
```

[image: UnCollapsed html structure]

Last Image is what the website looks like normally

[image: Website Normal View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are very close. One issue I see is that with `postContainer` you are looping through the OL tags but there is only one. You need to loop through the LIs under the OL so I changed your first locator.

Variable naming is important. It helps you read the code but also to debug the code while you are writing or in the future if it needs to be updated, etc. I changed some of your variable names to be more consistent with what's on the page. I added some more labels and then indented the labels so that it's easier to see the title then the subitems for that title.

```
articles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#post_list2 > li')
for article in articles:
    print('Title:', article.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3').text)
    print('  Thumbnail:', article.find_element_by_css_selector('img').get_attribute('src'))
    print('  Green categories:')
    for category in article.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.cat-category'):
        print('    ', category.text)
    print('  Brown categories:')
    for category in article.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.cat-category2'):
        print('    ', category.text)
```